# Can we have nonsimple graph from random graph?

Tags: graph-theory

From the definition given by Alon and Spencer:

> Let $n$ be a positive integer, $ 0 \leq p \leq 1$. The random graph
>   $G(n,p)$ is a probability space over the set of graphs on the vertex
>   sex $\{1,...,n\}$ determined by Pr$[\{i,j\} \in G] = p$ with these
>   events mutually independent.

It seems here that there is no restriction from having nonsimple graph.

But the definition given in Newman's Network:

> $G(n,p)$ is the ensemble of networks with $n$ vertices in which each
>   simple graph $G$ appears with probability $P(G) = p^m(1-p)^{{n \choose2}-m}$, where $m$ is the number of edges in the graph, and non-simpe
>   graphs have probability zero.

Clearly from this definition there is no nonsimple graphs? But how is that consistent with Alon's definition?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please describe how you anticipate a nonsimple graph arising through the Alon/Spencer definition.  Each edge either does or does not appear; there is no provision for it to appear more than once, nor for a loop to appear.

Comment: @vadim123 i got what you mean. thanks